# Why do nouns change gender in plural?

Tags: noun

On this site http://german.about.com/library/anfang/blanfang15.htm nouns have different genders in plural forms, why?Also is there a site where I can check the gender of nouns?

Comment: Plural nouns have no gender, they're just plural (you may treat plural as a kind of gender of its own, if you like). As for the gender of nouns, any dictionary lists the gender for susbtantives.

Comment: @karoshi Aehm, I'd like to stay feminine (eine Frau), even when meeting with others (Frauen).....

Comment: @Stephie of course. I hope you understand what I wanted to say. In the plural, there's no gender indicator in articles etc.; they follow a declination of their own.

Comment: Excellent question. Of course, good questions get regularly downvoted on stack sites, but nonetheless it was an excellent question because I also wanted to know why the gender changes for plural. Turns out it technically doesn't, but the word for the feminine gender is used for all 3. Thanks for asking this great question.

Comment: @germanaddict: "the word for the feminine gender is used for all 3" - this statement seems misleading. I would recommend to re-read [Stephie's answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/20173/5999), which, although you may find it "unnecessarily wordy and long-winded", correctly points out that 'for plural the definite article is always "die", but should not be confused with feminine singular "die"'. Plural nouns do not use the feminine article any more than feminine nouns use the plural article.

Comment: It's literally the same word, you're splitting hairs. DIE = DIE, it doesn't matter what is used where, it is the SAME WORD.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps you should have a short look at the gender of nouns:

The gender (not to be confused with "sex") is a property of nouns.

The German language has three genders, male, female and neuter.

- Usually a noun has *one specific* gender,
- for some, *two are permissible* (e.g my pet peeve "das/die Schorle"),
- sometimes different genders denote *different things*, e.g. der Laster (Lorry) / das Laster (vice).

The gender can usually be determined by a quick look at the article (both definite or indefinite) or matching adjectives and their declension, but also every decent dictionary should *always* state the gender with the noun.

What might have led you to the assumption that nouns change their gender is the fact that the pattern for the use of articles article is not the same as in English (definite: "the", both singular and plural; indefinite: "a" for singular, none for plural).

Basically, the definite article changes from singular to plural, **for plural the definite article is always "die", but should not be confused with feminine singular "die"**. Indefinite articles are dropped, similar to English.

male: der Tisch -> **die** Tische (but: ein Tisch -> Tische)
female: die Tasse -> **die** Tassen (but: eine Tasse -> Tassen) 
neuter: das Ziel -> **die** Ziele (but: ein Ziel -> Ziele)

Comment: An unnecessarily wordy and long-winded reply.

Comment: @germanaddict Thank you for your opinion and welcome to German SE. Although you have been around the network for quite a while, you may want to re-read the [Code of Conduct](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/conduct) and the [help] article about [comments](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) at your convenience

Comment: @germanaddict you will understand that this comment was premature as soon as you learn about other cases (der Tassen. den Tassen).

Comment: I stand by my comment that your reply was unnecessarily long-winded and does not concisely answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

German nouns don't change gender in plural. The thing that confuses you is that the articles der/die/das all have the same plural form die/die/die.

Examples:

- der Mann, die Männer (masculine in singular and plural)
- die Frau, die Frauen (feminine in singular and pl)
- das Kind, die Kinder (neuter in singular and pl).

Comment: Perhaps using Mann/Frau as examples might lead to confusion regarding the terms gender (-> grammar) and sex (-> biology)? I used "Kinder" myself... I just changed it.

Comment: @Stephie - Your post is okay, Stephie.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

The articles (der, die, das) go with singular objects. For plural, German uses the article "die". As a following the object seems to be of a different gender sometimes - but it isn't. It is just a double use of the same word I guess.

You can imagine it like the English "you" which can be both, plural or singular. The German "die" can be singular (only feminine) or plural, too :)